# How to get remainder of a division in assembly mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to find the remainder of division between t3 and t8 registers, and put the remainder in t1 register. I'm new to this language and every other solution I found was about other complex registers like AH or something I don't understand. How can I do this?

Comment: Use the `DIV` insrtuction,  it does both division and modulus.

Comment: `AH\` is for the x86 processor family, which is different from the MIPS family.